# MonoTouch: Build iOS app with mdtool from command line: Multiple provisioning profiles

Tags: iphone, jenkins, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mdtool

I want to build my ios-apps Appstore-ready directly from the command line with the mdtool from MonoTouch (Xamarin).

I use the following command:

```
'/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool' -v build '--configuration:AppStore|iPhone' MyAppProject.csproj
```

Now, in xCode, I have several provisioning profiles set up and *mdtool* seems to be confused which one to use:

[image]

Any chance to tell the *mdtool* the desired provisioning profile I want to use for that build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio, go to the "iOS Bundle Signing" section of your Project Options. That's where you can specify the Provisioning Profile and Code-sign keys for each build configuration.

Right now, you probably have it set to "Automatic" and so it doesn't know which one to choose because you have multiple provisions that match the CFBundleIdentifier value from your Info.plist

Comment: That's right, it's currently set to automatic. However, I want to fully automate the building process from the command line (Jenkins Continuous Integration) and the desired workflow is to build whatever version I want directly from Jenkins without needing to touch the Xamarin Studio at all.

Comment: Sure, but you still need to configure the Provisioning Profile and Code-Sign key to use for each build configuration (this info gets stored inside of the .csproj file)

Comment: Ahh, great. Now I see it in the .csproj file -> *CodesignProvision>BBDCD159-5E9B-49F2-838C-AB50B87DD2AB</CodesignProvision>*

I think I will automatically manipulate the .csproj file. Thanks for your help!